# CRM 2011: Campaign Activity Email via Mail Merge

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

If I try to send emails via "Email via Mail Merge" in a Campaign Activity with muliple user in the list, with some of them do not have the tag "send marketing data". I do not longer get a error(in the log) like it it's should do?

Thanks for the help

See this screenshot:

http://www.consultcrm.co.uk/sites/default/files/users/ryan-hale/nl2012-1.jpg 
the first two points under common are not shown in my system. How can I enable them

Update:

With Office 2010:
It seems that the CRM Addin crashes after/while sending the email: I will try to reinstall the Addin and will try again then.

```
Microsoft.Crm.Application.Outlook.WebFormsHost.exe, Version: 5.0.9690.2903, Zeitstempel: 0x51ef5168
crmaddin.dll, Version: 5.0.9690.2903, Zeitstempel: 0x51ef5373
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x00055a5b
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x27f8
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01cee69cff79a35d
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\res\web\bin\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Outlook.WebFormsHost.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\bin\crmaddin.dll
Berichtskennung: 7ec9a0bb-5290-11e3-bbdd-00155dc94936
```

With Office 2013:
Not working, no error

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: So are you saying that you don't see "E-mail Messages Created" and "Failures" in the left nav of the form?

Comment: @keerz yes, but mails are send

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this but it seems to depend on the async service running and the other thing I'd check is that you have the necessary privs. I usually start with admin and work my way backwards...:)

Comment: @keerz the user has sysadmin rights. and the async service is running on the server.

Comment: are you synced with the right org? see [here](http://crmuk.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/crm-2011-cant-create-activity-from-letter-via-mail-merge-campaign/)

Comment: @keerz as some users only have one org. yes, the sync is selected with the right org

Comment: @keerz but, yes that describes the Problem very good.

Comment: Have you tried contacting MS support?

Comment: @keerz no, I inteded too, but since as I got it working with the combination W7 / Office 2010, the Clients which use the Feature will be continuing to use this combination till Migration to CRM2013.